# After paying for my music ubuntu-one-music-store tells me my network is down, yet it's not!

Tags: ubuntu-one

After paying with paypal in "Ubuntu One Music-Store" it returns this message:

> **Internet connection is required to access the music store**
>   Please connect and reload.

Then when I press reload it returns the same message.
When I check into my Ubuntu One account on the web i don't see my purchased music.

What to do?

Comment: Your music should still be in your Ubuntu One account so you can get your music from there.

Comment: Voted to close, as this question seems to describe a (known, fixed) bug.

Comment: Voted to close - As it is a bug that has been fixed, its too localized.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug filed on Launchpad on this particular error message. See bug [#596394](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libubuntuone/+bug/596394).

However the [last comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libubuntuone/+bug/596394/comments/10) tells that the bug has been fixed:

```
This bug was fixed in the package libubuntuone - 0.9.1-0ubuntu1
  * New upstream release.
    - False connection error message (LP: #596394)
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange, in my case the Ubuntu One music store works flawlessly. You could check www.ubuntuforums.org and/or www.launchpad.net/ubuntu to see if there are more users with the same problem.

To log in to your Ubuntu One online account; https://one.ubuntu.com/